# remote desktop on microsoft windows 2003: licensing issue

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, licensing

it seems that I can't connect with remote desktop to a Windows 2003 machine cause of licensing issue.

I understand that if I connect only with one user it should work, what's the problem?

When I try to start the remote desktop licensing utility from administration menu, it shows a message that it could not find any licensing servers.

Is there a quick way to resolve this so I'll be able to remote desktop my machine ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have probably installed Terminal Services as an option when you installed the Server. You don't need this for Remote Desktop Admin use.

Comment: thanks.. the terminal server licensing was uninstalled but the terminal server was installed. once i removed it

Comment: Did uninstalling Terminal Server fix it?